# Getting the pmf from probability generating function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I uploaded a picture so that my question may be accurate. It is question 3a that I am struggling with.
I've learnt that the P(X=r)is the  rth derivative(w.r.t. t) of the pgf at t=0 . Divided by r factorial. But I am struggling to figure out how to obtain the rth derivative of this. Should I even try get the rth derivative or is there possibly an easier way?

Comment: 1) use the product rule to find the derivative. 2) yes, there's an easier way, if you can recognize what distribution it fits (try some algebraic manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

$$S(t)=\frac8{27}t^3\left(1-\frac{t}3\right)^{-3}=\frac8{27}t^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ldots\,\left(\frac{t}3\right)^n=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \ldots\,t^n$$

Comment: I apologise but could you please explain what you did and why?

Comment: I showed you how to expand $S(t)$ as a series, if only you complete the dots.